# How to make a CSS file used in LWC cross browser compatible?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, html5, css3

I have a CSS file with different style classes incorporated in it and this CSS file is being used in LWC. Now what I found it's coming up fine in Chrome but not in Mozilla or Safari browser. How to make the CSS compatible for cross browser use?

Example: content of css file something like below:

```
.horizontal{
    max-width: 17px;
    min-width: 18px;
    min-height: 18px;
    margin: 10px 0px 42px -6px;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [tool like this](https://www.browseemall.com/Compatibility/ValidateCSS) which will tell you if your CSS is compatible with each browser and the reason why it is not.